# Briefing news not updating on S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, alarm, news-and-weather

I have set up a `Briefing` alarm clock. I love hearing news when I wake up.

The problem is that since a week the synthetic voice of Samsung always reads me the same headline. Right now I tried to recreate the problem setting a briefing alarm. Right now, the news got updated, but reading the screen I found something the voice doesn't tell: the article was written on 16/3 and today is 20!!

News should always be fresh. There is always something new for Reuters to write...

Anybody had the same experience? Anybody knows if the app needs tweaking? I don't think it's a DroidWall problem otherwise I couldn't get any news!

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem now I finally worked it out basically you need to go to widget on your phone and  look for yahoo news. Then drag yahoo news to your screen and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Actually I have **disabled** Yahoo News application (and it's also Droidwall-blocked), so **that** suggested me this is not the correct answer. @downvoters you might have added a comment............ :)